# Helm upgrade error. atlassian-jira-software ingress

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, jira, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

Trying to update helm ingress jira atlassian software.
I have such ingress template:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "atlassian-jira-software.fullname" . -}}
{{- $servicePort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- $ingressPath := .Values.ingress.path -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "atlassian-jira-software.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "atlassian-jira-software.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ . }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ $ingressPath }}
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port:
                  name: http
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Execute this command:

**helm upgrade --dry-run -n atlassian jira .**

The output of this command:

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: Ingress "jira-atlassian-jira-software" in namespace "atlassian" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "jira"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "atlassian"`

**kubectl version --short**

The output:

`Client Version: v1.19.12 Server Version: v1.19.13-eks-8df270`
Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

Was the ingress originally installed by Helm? Check out its "labels" section:

```
kubectl get ingress jira-atlassian-jira-software -o json
```

If you don't find the expected values (as described in the error messages) and you are sure you know what you are doing, you can try adding the labels yourself by editing the ingress:

```
kubectl edit ingress jira-atlassian-jira-software
```

If you do this, make sure that you run a diff before you do the helm upgrade again (to ensure that you see what is going to happen in advance and that you don't blow away anything you did not intend to):

```
helm diff upgrade -n atlassian jira .
```

Comment: `kubectl get ingress jira-atlassian-jira-software -o json`
The output:
`"labels": {
            "app": "atlassian-jira-software",
            "chart": "atlassian-jira-software-0.1.0",
            "heritage": "Helm",
            "release": "jira"
        },`
So, it was deployed by helm.

I run the helm diff and then tried to upgrade it - the same error)

Comment: It sounds like the chart may have been installed by Helm Classic, but you have installed a newer version of Helm on your client. I imagine you could try reinstalling Helm Classic. Or you could edit the ingress to add the required labels for your current version of Helm (the labels and values are listed explicitly in your error message) using the command I provided…but be very careful and make sure to run the diff.